# How do you remove product from shopping cart?

Tags: commerce

I have three product variations: Postpaid, Prepaid, and Accessories. I can't seem to figure out why when I add a product with the Accessories product variation, I'm unable to remove it from the Shopping Cart. However with the Postpaid and Prepaid product variation I am able to. Also, previously someone took care of the store, and I can't get support anymore.

I double checked the workflow Rules, and can't seem to find the options. I know it's not a view issue, because it shows the remove link with the Postpaid product variation.

My only work around is to add a new product through the Postpaid and Prepaid product variation, but I don't really want to do this because it's messy.

Please see screenshot below.

[image: Shopping Cart Issue]

Answer (score 2):

If that button is missing for some reason on just a specific product type, then it's more than likely the result of custom form altering in a module file on your site. I'm not aware of any Views configuration that could remove that button just for products of a certain type. Just in case, you can check your shopping cart form View's configuration for the line item delete button to see if any advanced settings are somehow hiding it conditionally.

My hunch is on custom code, though.

Comment: I checked the Views configuration for the shopping Cart, and don't see any advanced settings for the line item delete button. Most likely custom code from the person that created the site originally.

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to fix this issue, I found the custom module, the previous developer added, and added the new line item types, and it worked perfectly.